# Multiple Google Analytics Events triggered on the same site by Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have the following use case: We have a job platform where you can apply for multiple jobs at once. So there is a list of checkboxes which a user selects and then he hits apply to send the applications.
Can I somehow fire one Google Analytics Event per selected checkboxes after the user has clicked on apply?

I have figured out that I get how many checkboxes are selected using this javascript:

```
let input = [...document.getElementsByTagName("Input")];
checkboxes = input.slice(2, input.length - 3);
let applications = checkboxes.map(checkboxes => checkboxes.checked).filter(Boolean).length;
```

The goal now is to trigger as many GA Events on the same page, as the number in the application variable.
In GA we have a goal where we want to collect every application as one event.

Not sure if and how this is possible.

Comment: You can iterate through the applications and trigger a dataLayer event per application. Then in GTM, setup a trigger based on that dataLayer event and attach it to a "event" tag.

Comment: Thanks, do you think that makes more sense than my solution underneath?

Comment: Are you using analytics.js or GTM?

Comment: GTM and a Universal Analytics Tag in there.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now like this:

```
multiApplyTracking = {
  track: function track() {
    var input = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("Input"));
    checkboxes = input.slice(2, input.length - 3);
    var applications = checkboxes.map(function(checkboxes) {
      return checkboxes.checked;
    }).filter(Boolean).length;
    console.log("Number of Applications: " + applications);
    if ("ga" in window) {
      var tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
      if (tracker)
        for (i = 0; i < applications; i++) {
          tracker.send("event", "User Application", "Apply");
          console.log("Application tracked!");
        }
    }
  }
};
multiApplyTracking.track();
```

This sends out a tracking event for every checked checkbox. This gets triggered as custom HTML when the user click on the submit button on the form.